# Springboot Multi-tenancy does not work with multi-threading

Tags: multithreading, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, multi-tenant

I have referenced this link to implement springboot multi-tenancy for two data sources - different databases(same schemas though) - https://anakiou.blogspot.in/2015/08/multi-tenant-application-with-spring.html

It works fine till I did not introduce any multi-threading in my application.

When I added a ExecutorService to do inserts in multiple tables for every record in a csv file - I saw the new threads did not contain information of the original tenant identifier that the rest service call was made with.

Instead, it started using the default tenant in the new threads.

How can we solve this? Will really appreciate any pointers.

EDIT 1: ExecutorService code: Trying to set current tenant as below:

```
List<Future<Output>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<Output>>();
        for (int j = 0; j < myList.size(); j++) {

            final Output output= myList.get(j);

            Future<Output> future = executorService.submit(new Callable<Output>() {
                @Override
                public Output call() throws Exception {
                    **TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(<current tenant goes here>);**
                    Output currentOutput= someService.executeQueries(output);
                    return currentOutput;
                }
            });
            futures.add(future);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal approach to propagate the tenant is by using `ThreadLocal`s.  In the blog example, it is using the class [RequestContextHolder](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html) to store the whole request in a ThreadLocal and then resolving the tenant from there.

When you are changing the thread, thread locals are lost in the new thread unless you take care of setting them again.

Comment: Thanks! I provided an EDIT 1 in the description after your answer to check how the current tenant can be set while creating multiple threads. Is this what you meant?